# How to add background color to every data plot (x,y value) of line chart: MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I need to set the background color of every data plot (each x/y value) of the line chart. As an example, in the figure below, the background of 82.4 value is set to orange(complete fill). Likewise, I want to add this background to every other value as well i.e. 42.1, 59.3, and 68.7
I am using the Line Chart of MPAndroidChart:
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

[image: Add background to each data plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Entry` constructor that takes in a `Drawable` icon:

```kotlin
Entry(
    0f,
    0f,
    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
        resources,
        R.drawable.rect_blue_trans,
        context?.theme
    )
)
```

The icon will be drawn (unfortunately) on top of the value label, so you have to make sure that the drawable has some transparency. Also make sure that the drawable has a fixed size (in my case 16dp x 16dp):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="16dp" android:width="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="#662E349B" />
</shape>
```

Then, when creating the `DataSet` out of the `Entries` make sure to enable value and icon drawing. Also you will probably have to play around with the `iconsOffset` to properly position the icon:

```
dataSet.apply {
    setDrawValues(true)
    setDrawIcons(true)
    iconsOffset = MPPointF.getInstance(0f, -8f) // try different offsets for yourself
}
```

This would result in chart values drawn like this (I have some of my own styling here, but it should be roughly similar):

[image]

Comment: Is there any best way to add padding to the line between data plots i.e. line passing through the background of the values should be hidden within backgrounds and only visible outside the box? From the above figure, the yellow line connecting the 0,1, and 2 values should be visible only outer sides of their backgrounds.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to add padding to the lines.

Comment: Is there any hack that will address this issue?

Comment: I think a hack would be to have a drawable that is somehow parameterized with a number (the value of the data plot in that case) that will be displayed on that drawable and this drawable would be passed to the `Entry` constructor. The drawable wouldn't have to have any transparency and thus would cover the lines on the chart. But I don't know if it is possible to have such a drawable displaying a given number. You can try to research on that more.